# Android focus related issue

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have one `RelativeLayout` in which i have 5 buttons, I hide this `RelativeLayout` after screen timeout (If there is no user activity), and when user does some activity then i set it as visible.

But problem is that, when i set the `RelativeLayout` as invisible then it removes focus from its child, and when i set it back to visible then it just sets the focus to first child.

I need to set the focus to the previously focused child of the `RelativeLayout` to be maintained when i set it as visible or invisible.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you use visiblity INVISIBLE instead of gone here?

Comment: Dheeresh i am using INVISIBLE not GONE.

Comment: you can also manually set focus using object.requestFocus(); in java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Global Variable.. 
  View v;


//beore you hiding the buttons 
v = getCurrentFocus ();




//after you showing the buttons 
 if(null!=v && v. isFocusable ())
    v.requestFoucs();
```